# After executing some operations on an init variable, I am getting 'None' returned, why is that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class Pitch_Class_Set(object):

    def __init__(self, pitches):
        self.pitches = pitches
        print(self.pitches)
        print(list(set([int(i) % 12 for i in self.pitches.split()])).sort())

setterino = Pitch_Class_Set(input('> '))
```

Result:

> > 1 8 9
>
> 1 8 9
>
> None

I can't quite figure out why self.pitches is returning the correct result, while the code after isn't returning:

> [1, 8, 9]

Comment: because `sort` is an in-place operation; it returns `None`. You're after `sorted`.